# How to set a default group on an Identity Provider in Keycloak

Tags: oauth, keycloak, openid-connect, keycloak-services, keycloak-connect

In Keycloak, is there a way to assign users to a default group when those user sign in over an Identity Provider?

Note: This already works with roles. E.g. `navigate to Identity Provider` → `select Provider` → `Mappers` → `New` → `Hardcoded Role` → `select Role` → `Save`. However, such a Mapper seems to be missing for selecting groups.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

One would assume that such a mapper would exist, but unfortunately, until the most recent version it does not. However, aside from extending and creating your own mapper, you can do the following workaround:

- Navigate to the identity provider configuration;
- Select the IDP;
- Go to Mappers and click in create;
- As `Mapper Type` select `Advanced Claim to Group`
- Add a `Key` and `Value` claims that you know will always be present in all the tokens coming from the IDP, regardless of the user;
- For example, 'exp' as a key, and '*' has the value. For this particular example, you would need to enable the 'Regex Claim Values' option;
- In the field `Group` select the group to be automatically added by default to all users coming the external IDP;
- Click on save.

If you login via the external IDP with a given user, you should see that the user belongs to the group that you have set. To check that, go to users > select the desired user > Tab Groups.

---

The other option would be to use the [default group feature](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#proc-specifying-default-groups_server_administration_guide):

> To automatically assign group membership to any users who is created
> or who is imported through Identity Brokering, you use default groups.

The problem is that the default group will be assigned to your new users regardless of the IDP (or use federation they came from), which might be undesirable.

**On the old Keycloak UI**

[image]

**On the new Keycloak UI**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for other Keycloak versions, but on version `16.1.x` the `Hardcoded Group` mapper doesn't exist. Nor do the `Advanced Claim to Role/Group` mappers for certain IDP providers (for Google for example). The "Advanced Claim..." mappers are available for the OIDC type IDP providers though.